# High-level library for 2D interactive graphics

Tags: library, programming, drawing, vector-graphics, pixel-graphics

I am looking for a software library / component with the following capabilities:

- Manage spatial (position, shape, size) information about 2D objects
- Render those objects to screen / image
- Handle keyboard & mouse interactions / events
- Provide a high-level API for interaction with and configuration

The application this is for will be showing "business graphics" that the user can interact with and manipulate visually. We'd like to avoid handling low-level drawing, mouse click detection, etc.

We are working in a .NET environment but this library need not necessarily be native .NET, being compatible is sufficient.